# Spreading a list contained in a data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr

A handy trick (especially for stat testing) is to convert a wide data.frame to a long data.frame with embedded lists.

```
df <- data.frame(
    A = sample(c(1:10),1000,replace = TRUE), 
    B = sample(c(1:10),1000,replace = TRUE), 
    C = sample(c(1:10),1000,replace = TRUE)) %>% 
    gather %>% group_by(key) %>% 
    summarize(response_list = list(value))
```

Given a data.frame with an embedded list, how do I append summary counts for each of the embedded lists so that the data.frame looks like this:

```
key response_list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
A   list()        x x x x x x x x x x 
...
```

where, x, is a respective count of the occurrence of each number in the embedded list (akin to `table(factor(the_list())`)

Comment: Downvote with no comment?

Comment: table provides frequency counts, so not clear what you are asking I guess, to whoever down voted?

Comment: Yes it does provide the counts, but it doesn't append it to the data frame as a new set of columns as per the example provided.

Comment: Hopefully not asking the obvious, but why not just `cbind` the result of `do.call(rbind, lapply(your_df, table))` or something like that?

Comment: cbind(df, t(apply(df[, 2], 1, function(x) table(x))))

Comment: I tried these, but the display was all messed up so I thought I was doint it wrong. It looks like it just needed to be class `tbl_df` to be displayed as I was expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df <- cbind(df, do.call(rbind, lapply(df$response_list, table)))
tbl_df(df)
# Source: local data frame [3 x 12]
#
#      key response_list     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
#   (fctr)         (chr) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int)
# 1      A   <int[1000]>    97   105    97   100   103   103    86   101    90   118
# 2      B   <int[1000]>    98   100   108    92   115    87   101   105    98    96
# 3      C   <int[1000]>   109    97    87    92    91    90   114   109   104   107
```